# Which is not searching full $PATH

Tags: bash, sudo, path, which

If I run `sudo which abc` I would expect it to search the superusers $PATH for the program 'abc', but it looks like it only searches a subset.

I can see this by running `sudo echo $PATH` and comparing the paths searched.

```
$ sudo which abc
which: no abc in (/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin)

$ sudo echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/aws/bin:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin
```

What is happening here?

Comment: And where is `abc` actually located ?

Comment: Note that `sudo echo $PATH` will not show root's $PATH.  gets resolved by current she'll and then passed to sudo....

Comment: Also note that if you use sudo to actually execute `abc`, it is typically configured to search its own `secure_path` rather than the root user's `PATH`. See `man sudoers`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$PATH` is expanded before `sudo` is run. Therefore you are seeing the value of `PATH` for you, and not for the user you sudo to.

try this instead:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'
```